# Print weighted color palette in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I understand that one can print a color palette (equally weighted) with the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
blue_red = [(0,0,255), (255, 0,0)]  # or any other list of RGB tuples
plt.imshow([blue_red])
```

However, how could I show weighted palettes? For example if I wanted to weight 90% blue and 10% red instead of 50-50?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
blue = (0,0,255)
red = (255, 0,0)
weight1 = 9
weight2 = 1
blue_red = [blue for _ in range (weight1)] + [red for _ in range(weight2)]
plt.imshow([blue_red])
plt.show()
```

or simply:

```
plt.imshow([[(0,0,255) for _ in range(9)] + [(255, 0,0) for _ in range(1)]])
```

[image]

You can also add an extent argument to clean up your corrdinates:

```
plt.imshow([[(0,0,255) for _ in range(9)] + [(255, 0,0) for _ in range(1)]],extent=[0,10,0,1])
```

[image]